# pdf preview in browser in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

i'm having a trouble to preview my generated pdf file in browser when clicking a button 
i used Reponse.Redirect to pdf location but all i get is the older version of the pdf file, in my application i'm trying to rewrite in the same output pdf file, when i open the pdf with acrobat reader it displays the new content but when i try with the browser it displays the older content i'm using asp.net and iTextsharp for pdf generation.

this is the sample code i'm using to call the pdf file

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.Scheme + System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host + "/PDF/BILLET_6000.pdf");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if acrobat displays the new content then may be cleaning up your browser's cache would fetch the new file from the location specified.

Comment: yeah it seems that this is the problem i give it a try it works for the first but then after the same issue pops up, is there any way to clear cache of the browser before redirecting the user to the new generated pdf. and thank you for your answer

Comment: The trick is to give a unique url to your pdf file like this "Response.Redirect(Request.Url.Scheme + System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host + "/PDF/BILLET_6000.pdf?nt=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());". Hope this works.